# Ops, an error occurred

Tags: mashape

Mashape don't give me any support unless its working hours so i hope you can give me some answers

I'm trying to upload a file throught my API.

Dose anyone know why mashape generates this kind of error? what it means or how to fix it or avoid it. Its not coming from my server. And It's not something my API would ever return. Making a request directly to my API works as it should!

```
[body]    => {"message":"Ops, an error occurred (╯°□°）╯"}
[status]  => 500 Internal Server Error
[headers] => 
   access-control-allow-credentials:true
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Length:54
   Content-Type:application/json
   Date:Sun, 23 Aug 2015 18:34:27 GMT
   Server:Mashape/5.0.6
   X-Mashape-Proxy-Response:true
```

To me it seems like its a problem with Mashapes proxy?

**EDIT**

Some more investigation shows me that it has to do with the size

```
var content = "kokokoko".repeat(1200); // Uploading a small file works fine
// var content = "kokokoko".repeat(1300); // Uploading a larger file produce the error above
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append("format", 'ttf');
fd.append("file", new Blob([content]), "filename.ext");

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://ofc.p.mashape.com/directConvert/', 
  headers: {'X-Mashape-Key': 'xxxxx'},
  method:"post",
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
})
```

**EDIT 2**
It works now, but still doesn't explain the message `Ops, an error occurred (╯°□°）╯` means

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring for me currently.this particular error response is from the maspahe proxy  and not the underlying service.  Submitted a help ticket.